# FF and IE issues when trying to detect text overflow, works fine in Chrome

Tags: css

I ran across this issue in FF and IE , it works fine in Chrome.
I am trying to detect whether there is a text overflow.

It appears  scrollWidth is set to visible text width plus padding (which I guess is part of visible) as long as overflow text is less than padding. Hence when I compare offsetWidth and scrollWidth to determine whether there is overflow, the test fails since they both include padding in their calculations and therefore the values are equal. However if my text is long enough so that "overflow" string is larger than padding, it works fine.

So for example if I have a string "abcdef123" and it shows "abcdef..." and I have enough padding so that "123" can fit there, scrollWidth is equal to offsetWidth.
However if I have a string "abcdef123456" so that "123456" length is larger than my padding, scrollWidth is larger than offsetWdith and text overflow is detected properly.
It works fine in Chrome.

Has anyone seen that and was able to find workaround ?

Comment: To get better help, you'd better post a sample code reflecting your question and create a working example at a website like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You added the `j` tag to your question, is that accurate? Or did you mean JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue right now, I could use your help.